# Re-enrollment after upgrading Apple Push Certificate

Tags: apple-push-notifications, mdm

Can anyone confirm that after changing the Apple Push Certificate to follow the new steps, you have to re-enroll all the devices?

I have tried creating the CSR based on the existing P12 key store, and afterwards creating a new P12 key store with the Apple signed public key. When using this new key store I am able to enroll devices, but all devices already enrolled needs to be re-enrolled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much search I found the answer at [McAfee](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB73899&actp=LIST).

> If you obtained your previous MDM certificate using an Apple Developer's Account your old certificate has been migrated to the new Apple Push Certificates Portal...

This explains everything. A my work we have one idep user that created the old certificate for me. When I signed in using my own Apple ID, naturally I was not able to see the migrated certificate.